# Sending a SOAP request to some URL in Spring Boot

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, soap

I'm trying to send a request to an a SOAP API from my Spring Boot app. The request object I generate starts and ends with tags like `<pricing>`. But I keep getting an error from the API saying wrong version. I'm really lost on how I can properly generate a full XML request in the correct format and send it .I also should note tht i already have my java objects and don t have the api's wsdl.is it possible.

Comment: You should check the documentation of this particular API. Probably there is a tag with a correct version needed.

Comment: I didn t know how to add the soap eveloppe with the information needed.I am just sending a  requrst starting with the tag <pricing>

Answer (score 0):

Your SOAP message must have a XML version tag, the envelope and body. Like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
<soap:Body>
... here goes your XML message
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: But how can i generate it